# how to disable datatable button using jquery

Tags: jquery, button, datatable

```
$('td:last-child a:eq(0)', nRow).remove();
```

This code will remove the button but I need the button to be shown but to be disabled, the user should not be able to click it.

Answer (score 3):

Use `disable` property for disabling the button.

Implies your code should be

```
$('td:last-child a:eq(0)', nRow).prop('disabled', true);
```

For further reference : [HTML Button disable](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_disabled.asp)

-Help :)

Comment: I tried this code but not working.. datatable is not loading when prop is used

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td:last-child a:eq(0)', nRow).prop('disabled', true);
```

or

```
$('td:last-child a:eq(0)', nRow).css('disabled', 'disabled');
```